# Selecting a text input from a table located in a specific row

Tags: jquery

I have table like this-

```
<table class='table'>
  <tr>
   <td class="td"><input type="text" name="name<%=f.getId()%>" value="<%=f.getName()%>"/>      
   </td>
   <td class="td"><input type="text" id="field_length" size="3" name="length<%=f.getId()%>" value="<%=f.getLength()%>"/></td>
   <td class="td"><input type="text" name="tooltip<%=f.getId()%>" value="<%=f.getToolTip()%>"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   same like the previous.......
  </tr>
  <tr>
    same like previous....
  </tr>
```

Now I want to change the value in the text box located in the second row with the id "field_length". I tried to use jquery to do that.

```
$(‘tr:nth-child(2) input:text#field_length’).val(10);
```

But this is not working. Can any body please provide me a little help regarding this.

Comment: Just use the `id` to select the input, if you have multiple elements with the same `id` you have invalid html, and should correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead, just select the input with name starting with length instead of the faulty ID construction. The first part of the element names are fixed ... you can remove the IDs if you want with this solution.

```
$("table tr:nth-child(2) input:text[name^=length]").val(10);
```

[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Yoeri/Xkt3h/8/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Yoeri. That looks better. But another problem is there I have another table as well, which I dont want to fiddle with. Can I specefy this table only in your suggested jquery code?

Comment: does the table have an ID? If yes, $("table#TABLEID tr:nth-child(2) input:text[name^=length]").val(10);

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique, you can select the element by using the id selector:

```
$('#field_length').val(10)
```

> What I need is to change the value for all the text boxes in every row except the first one.

You can try:

```
$('input:not(:first)').val(10)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but that is changing the value of the text box in the first row. But not for others. What I need is to change the value for all the text boxes in every row except the first one.

Comment: @SomSarkar Hi, this happens when you have used an ID for several elements, IDs must be unique.

Comment: Hi Raminson...actually this table is getting populated through a for loop. Thats why all the rows will have a td with same id. The code that you suggested is changing the value of all the rows. Thanks for that. But is it possible to do something so that I can change the values of the text boxes, one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Your first td ends with another td instead of /td.
BTW, as you explained how you built your table, you will get several elements with same ID which is not permitted, IDs are supposed to be unique, as Raminson mentioned.
Finally, you could try to use each(). I'll post here how to if you need me to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. IT will be helpful if you can provide me that. Another thing can you tell me if I dont use the id then how can I change the value of the text box which is the second td and under a particular tr.

Comment: All right, no need of using each() in fact. Yoeri's solution looks ok to me, except that you have to select the row you need, not the nth-child.